# Displaying JSON data in the drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two **JSON** files called `contacts` and `workers`.

- I am displaying `name` of the  `contacts` using `*ngFor`.
- And also displaying `assigned workers` for each contact in the `dropdown` like this:

[image]

> But i want to display the `assigned workers` for each `contact` along with the full list of `workers`.

Like this:

[image]

So that i can change assigned workers.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-zifsd7?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over all workers list and bind the id into `workersId` field of contact.

```
<mat-select formControlName="worker" placeholder="Assign Wokers"  multiple [(ngModel)]="contact.workersId">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let worker of workers" [value]="worker.id">
        {{worker.name}}
    </mat-option> 
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Did you try in the demo? It had a mistake in contacts JSON. You used `assignedWorkersId` instead of `workersId`

Comment: Let me try in **demo**

Comment: I have checked still the the it doesn't work.

Comment: It worked for me. Can you change that JSON. I'll try again.

Comment: I got the expected result, Thank you..:)@Arcteezy